# How to address a formal email response to a 学会本部事務局 when you don't know if the person is a 教授 or not?

Tags: honorifics, formality, email, academic-japanese

I received the following email and I want to submit the 要旨, but should I address the body of my email to 加島 or to 本部事務局?
I did a Google search for her full name but I didn't find it on a university website, so I don't know if she should be addressed as 先生 or as さん.

> 日本基督教学会本部事務局の加島と申します。第63回学術大会での研究発表のご希望を受け付けました。（正式には、7月中旬の理事・幹事による承認を経て、研究発表が認められます）。
>
> 今後の予定をご紹介いたします。
>
> １．6月19日（金）まで研究発表の要旨を400字程度にまとめ、本部事務局までお送りください。これは、理事・幹事による研究発表審査のためのものです。理事・幹事が内容を確認しますので、誤字・脱字等にもご注意ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use さん in a formal email.

I think "**事務局の**加島" means she is probably a clerical staff rather than a teacher. (Of course it's a good idea to check it using Google search) So the safe choice would be to address her as 加島**様**.